# Jquery find() function

Tags: jquery

So this is the markup

```html
<ul class="level_1">
<li></li>
</li></li>
</li class="has-2"></li>
</li class="has-2"></li>
</li class="has-2"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="level_1">
</li class="has-2"></li>
</li class="has-2"></li>
</li class="has-2"></li>
<li></li>
</li></li>
</ul>
```

I've been trying to find first `li` that has a class `has-2` in two `ul` and apply some css to that first `li`. so I'm trying the following jquery.

```js
<script>
 $( ".level_1").find("li.has-2" ).first().css( "clear", "both" );
</script>
```

But the clear:both is applying to the first `li.has-2` in first `ul` but not to the first `li.has-2` in second `ul`. Am i doing anything wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: need to tell you about a bad markup you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `:first-child` selector **and also your tag format (markup) is wrong its `<li></li>` not `</li></li>`**

```js
$( ".level_1").find("li.has-2:first-child" ).css( "color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="level_1">

<li class="has-2">asdas</li>
<li class="has-2">asdasd</li>
<li class="has-2">asdasd</li>
</ul>
<ul class="level_1">
<li class="has-2">asdasd</li>
<li class="has-2">asdas</li>
<li class="has-2">asdasd</li>
<li></li>
<li><li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of you need to fix the markup for ul elements:

```
<ul class="level_1">
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li class="has-2"></li>
 <li class="has-2"></li>
 <li class="has-2"></li>
</ul>
```

Then, you need to use  `:first-child` selector instead of `.first()`.

> Selects all elements that are the first child of their parent.

```
$( ".level_1").find("li.has-2:first-child" ).css( "clear", "both" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `eq()` instead of `first()` [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/edg6jqw2/2/)

Html Here

```
<ul class="level_1">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li class="has-2"></li>
<li class="has-2"></li>
<li class="has-2"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="level_1">
<li class="has-2"></li>
<li class="has-2"></li>
<li class="has-2"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Modified Jquery Here

```
  $(".level_1").each(function() {    
     $(this).find("li.has-2").eq(0).css("clear", "both");    
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! but the code is just applying only to the first li.has-2 in first ul .but we need that to apply to the first li.has-2 in second ul also and first li.has-2 in thrid ul soon on :)

Answer (score 1):

First, write your markups properly. Then you can do:

```js
$('ul.level_1').find('li.has-2:first').css('clear','both');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="level_1">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li class="has-2"></li>
<li class="has-2"></li>
<li class="has-2"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="level_1">
<li class="has-2"></li>
<li class="has-2"></li>
<li class="has-2"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :first as :first-selector does not match your requirement

```js
$(".level_1").find("li.has-2:first").css("clear", "both").css('background-color', 'green');
```

```css
.has-2 {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="level_1">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li class="has-2">3</li>
  <li class="has-2">4</li>
  <li class="has-2">5</li>
</ul>
<ul class="level_1">
  <li class="has-2">1</li>
  <li class="has-2">2</li>
  <li class="has-2">3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `:first` with `.each()`:

```
$(".level_1").each(function() {
  $(this).find("li.has-2:first").css("clear", "both");
});
```

```js
$(".level_1").each(function() {
  $(this).find("li.has-2:first").css("color", "red"); // just for the sake of visual.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="level_1">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="has-2">aaa</li>
  <li class="has-2">aaa</li>
  <li class="has-2">aaa</li>
</ul>
<ul class="level_1">
  <li class="has-2">aaa</li>
  <li class="has-2">aaa</li>
  <li class="has-2">aaa</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```